# pfsense with 4 WAN IP and outgoing NAT

Tags: virtual-machine, nat, bridge, pfsense

I have a pfsense with a single wan ip, i want to assign multiple wan ip's. The pfsense machine is located on a vm machine with the other servers i wish to NAT forward. I want to give each server a wan ip address. The servers are all connected to the firewall with a internal virtual network interface. Can someone can help me on how to configure pfsense to NAT correctly.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Nat section of the PFSense, there is a one to one TAB that allows mapping option to allow all traffic on an exteranl IP to map to an internal IP. It is pretty straight forward. There are some other configs you will need to add.

You will need virtaul IP's for all of your external IPs on the Wan interface.

You will need to set up the rules to allow the NAT to occure

[PFsense 1:1 NAT](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/1:1_NAT)

[Simple Step by Step Guide For 1:1 Nat](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=13507.0)